# How do you denote the gradient with $dy/dx$ notation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

With a gradient function $f'(x)$ you can show the gradient at any x coordinate easily. How do you do this with $dy/dx$ notation?

Comment: Do you mean "How do you write $f'(5)$ with $dy/dx$ notation"?

Comment: You can use $$\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x=5}.$$

Comment: What's wrong with $\frac{df}{dx}(5)$?

Comment: @Arthur it looks like the differential multiplied by 5

Comment: Doesn't $f(5)$ look like the function multiplied by $5$? Ok, then $\frac{df(5)}{dx}$? My point is, the derivative is a function, and as such can be evaluated at a point just as any other function. Why not use the established notation?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I would recommend posting that as an answer so this no longer is on the unanswered questions list.

Comment: @Arthur, without something like what Yves wrote, $\frac{df}{dx}$ is usually taken to mean something like "the derivative of $f$ evaluated at the variable $x$", so that your first proposal conflicts with most calculus textbooks. For your second proposal, since $f(5)$ is a constant, it looks like that should be $0$ in the convention of most books, but I think I might have seen something like that once or twice.

Comment: @MarkS.: feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

An unambiguous, if cumbersome, notation is presented in [Yves Daoust](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/65203/yves-daoust)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248100/how-do-you-denote-the-gradient-with-dy-dx-notation?noredirect=1#comment4622946_2248100).

$$f'(5)=\left.\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}\right|_{x=5}$$

I couldn't easily find a particularly authoritative source online, but the "Alternate Notation" note at the bottom of [Paul's Math Notes on the definition of the derivative](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DefnOfDerivative.aspx) presents this notation.